# DirectX9 Lighting C++ Lighting not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, directx-9

This is a simple program that draws a 3d cube with a texture. The problem is I can not see the texture because the lights are not working.I have turned off the lights just to make sure the texture is there and it is.So if any one can help me figure out why the lights are not working I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#include "DirectXGame.h"

DirectXGame::DirectXGame(void)
{
    //init to zero good pratice

    m_pD3DObject=0;
    m_pD3DDevice=0;
    m_currTime=0;
    m_prevTime=0;

    ZeroMemory(&m_D3Dpp,sizeof(m_D3Dpp));
    FOV=D3DXToRadian(65.0f);
    aspectRatio=800/600;
    nearPlane=1.0f;
    farPlane=1000.0f;
}

DirectXGame::~DirectXGame(void)
{
}

//create class for input
DirectXInput DXClass;
void DirectXGame::Initialize(HWND hWnd ,HINSTANCE hInst,bool bWindowed) // create the material struct)//
{
    // grab the window width and height fronm the HWND
    RECT r;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &r);
    m_nWidth = r.right - r.left;
    m_nHeight = r.bottom - r.top;
    m_bVSync = false;

    // Create the D3D Object
    m_pD3DObject = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    // Create our presentation parameters for our D3D Device
    m_D3Dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd; // Handle to the window
    m_D3Dpp.Windowed = bWindowed; // Windowed or Full-screen?
    m_D3Dpp.BackBufferCount = 1; // Number of back-buffers
    m_D3Dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8; // Back-buffer pixel format
    m_D3Dpp.BackBufferWidth = m_nWidth; // Back-buffer width
    m_D3Dpp.BackBufferHeight = m_nHeight; // Back-buffer height
    m_D3Dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD; // Swap effectm_bVSync ? D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT :
    m_D3Dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
    m_D3Dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = bWindowed ? 0 : D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT;
    m_D3Dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE; // Enable depth and stencil buffer
    m_D3Dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D24S8; // Depth/Stencil buffer bit format
    m_D3Dpp.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_DISCARD_DEPTHSTENCIL; // Discard the depth/stencil buffer upon Present()
    m_D3Dpp.MultiSampleQuality = 0; // MSAA quality
    m_D3Dpp.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE; // MSAA type

    // Check the device's capabilities
    DWORD deviceBehaviorFlags = 0;
    m_pD3DObject->GetDeviceCaps(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, &m_D3DCaps);

    // Determine vertex processing mode
    if(m_D3DCaps.DevCaps & D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING)
    {
        deviceBehaviorFlags |= D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING;
    }
    else
    {
        deviceBehaviorFlags |= D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING;
    }

    // if hardware vertex processing is on, check for pure
    if(m_D3DCaps.DevCaps & D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE && deviceBehaviorFlags & D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING)
    {
        deviceBehaviorFlags |= D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE;
    }

    // Create D3D Device
    m_pD3DObject->CreateDevice(
        D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, // Default display adapter
        D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, // Device type to use
        hWnd, // Handle to our window
        deviceBehaviorFlags, // D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSINGVertex Processing Behavior Flags (PUREDEVICE, HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING)
        &m_D3Dpp, // Presentation parameters
        &m_pD3DDevice); // Return a created D3D Device

    //=================================================================//
    // Create/Load Sprite & Font D3D and COM objects

    //Create font
    D3DXCreateFont(m_pD3DDevice, 23, 0, FW_BOLD, 0, true,
        DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY,
        DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, TEXT("Times New Roman"),
        &m_pD3DFont);

    //for font 1 "Name"
    RECT rct;
    rct.left=2;
    rct.right=780;
    rct.top=10;
    rct.bottom=rct.top+20;

    //MATRIX
    eyePos.x = 0;
    eyePos.y = 2;
    eyePos.z = -10;
    lookAt.x = 0;
    lookAt.y = 0;
    lookAt.z = 0;
    upVec.x = 0;
    upVec.y = 1;
    upVec.z = 0;

    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH( &view_Matrix, &eyePos, &lookAt, &upVec);

    m_pD3DDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_VIEW, &view_Matrix);

    // projection matrix
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &pro_Matrix, FOV, aspectRatio, nearPlane, farPlane);
    m_pD3DDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &pro_Matrix);

    // MATRIX: VertexElement Declaration
    D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 declaration[] =
    {
        {0, 0, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION, 0},
        {0, 12, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_NORMAL, 0},
        {0, 24, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT2, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 0},
        D3DDECL_END()
    };

    //LPDIRECT3DVERTEXDECLARATION9 m_pVtxDeclObject;
    // Create vertex declaration
    m_pD3DDevice->CreateVertexDeclaration(declaration,&vertDec);

    ///---CUBE: Vertex and Indicies :START---///
    // Load vertex info, listed per cube face quads
    // Front
    m_cubeVerts[0].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[1].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[2].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[3].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[0].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[1].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[2].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[3].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
    m_cubeVerts[0].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[1].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[2].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 0.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[3].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Back
    m_cubeVerts[4].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[5].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[6].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[7].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[4].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[5].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[6].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[7].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    m_cubeVerts[4].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[5].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[6].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[7].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Top
    m_cubeVerts[8].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[9].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[10].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[11].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[8].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[9].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[10].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[11].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    m_cubeVerts[8].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[9].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[10].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 0.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[11].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Bottom
    m_cubeVerts[12].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[13].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[14].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[15].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[12].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[13].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[14].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[15].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
    m_cubeVerts[12].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[13].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[14].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[15].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Left
    m_cubeVerts[16].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[17].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[18].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[19].position = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[16].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[17].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[18].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[19].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    m_cubeVerts[16].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[17].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[18].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 0.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[19].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Right
    m_cubeVerts[20].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[21].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[22].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[23].position = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[20].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[21].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[22].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&m_cubeVerts[23].normal, &D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    m_cubeVerts[20].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 1.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[21].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[22].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 0.0f);
    m_cubeVerts[23].uv = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Load index info, refers into index into verts array to compose triangles
    // Note: A clockwise winding order of verts will show the front face.

    // Front
    m_cubeIndices[0] = 0; m_cubeIndices[1] = 1; m_cubeIndices[2] = 2; // Triangle 0
    m_cubeIndices[3] = 0; m_cubeIndices[4] = 2; m_cubeIndices[5] = 3; // Triangle 1

    // Back
    m_cubeIndices[6] = 4; m_cubeIndices[7] = 5; m_cubeIndices[8] = 6; // Triangle 2
    m_cubeIndices[9] = 4; m_cubeIndices[10] = 6; m_cubeIndices[11] = 7; // Triangle 3

    // Top
    m_cubeIndices[12] = 8; m_cubeIndices[13] = 9; m_cubeIndices[14] = 10; // Triangle 4
    m_cubeIndices[15] = 8; m_cubeIndices[16] = 10; m_cubeIndices[17] = 11; // Triangle 5

    // Bottom
    m_cubeIndices[18] = 12; m_cubeIndices[19] = 13; m_cubeIndices[20] = 14; // Triangle 6
    m_cubeIndices[21] = 12; m_cubeIndices[22] = 14; m_cubeIndices[23] = 15; // Triangle 7

    // Left
    m_cubeIndices[24] = 16; m_cubeIndices[25] = 17; m_cubeIndices[26] = 18; // Triangle 8
    m_cubeIndices[27] = 16; m_cubeIndices[28] = 18; m_cubeIndices[29] = 19; // Triangle 9

    // Right
    m_cubeIndices[30] = 20; m_cubeIndices[31] = 21; m_cubeIndices[32] = 22; // Triangle 10
    m_cubeIndices[33] = 20; m_cubeIndices[34] = 22; m_cubeIndices[35] = 23; // Triangle 11
    ///---CUBE: Vertex and Indicies :END---///

    //create buffers
    // create a vertex buffer interface called i_buffer
    m_pD3DDevice->CreateVertexBuffer(4*6*sizeof(Vertex),
        D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY,
        0,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &VB,
        NULL);

    void* pVertices;
    // lock VB and load the vertices into it
    VB->Lock(0, 0,&pVertices, 0);

    // send array
    memcpy(pVertices, m_cubeVerts, 4*6*sizeof(Vertex));

    //unlock
    VB->Unlock();

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

    m_pD3DDevice->CreateIndexBuffer(3*12*sizeof(WORD), // 3 and 12
        D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY,
        D3DFMT_INDEX16,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &IB,
        NULL);

    void* pIndices;
    // lock index
    IB->Lock(0,0,&pIndices,0);
    //send array of indices to vram
    memcpy(pIndices, m_cubeIndices, 3*12*sizeof(WORD));

    //unlock index
    IB->Unlock();

    D3DLIGHT9 light;
    D3DMATERIAL9 m_Mat;

    ZeroMemory(&light, sizeof(light));
    // clear out the light struct for use
    light.Type = D3DLIGHT_POINT;
    // make the light type 'directional light'
    light.Diffuse.r = 0.5f;
    light.Diffuse.g = 0.5f;
    light.Diffuse.b = 0.5f;
    light.Diffuse.a = 1.0f;
    light.Ambient.r = 0.2f;
    light.Ambient.g = 0.2f;
    light.Ambient.b = 1.0f;
    light.Specular.r = 1.0f;
    light.Specular.g = 1.0f;
    light.Specular.b = 1.0f;
    // set the lighting position
    light.Position.x = 30;
    light.Position.y = 10;
    light.Position.z = -10;
    light.Range = 900.0f;
    light.Attenuation0 = 0.0f;
    light.Attenuation1 = 0.125f;
    light.Attenuation2 = 0.0f;
    m_pD3DDevice->SetLight(0, &light);
    // send the light struct properties to light #0
    m_pD3DDevice->LightEnable(0, TRUE);
    // turn on light #0
    ZeroMemory(&m_Mat, sizeof(m_Mat));
    // clear out the struct for use
    m_Mat.Diffuse.r = 1.0f;
    m_Mat.Diffuse.g = 0.0f;
    m_Mat.Diffuse.b = 0.0f;
    m_Mat.Diffuse.a = 0.0f;
    // set diffuse color to white
    m_Mat.Ambient.r = 0.2f;
    m_Mat.Ambient.g = 0.2f;
    m_Mat.Ambient.b = 0.2f;
    m_Mat.Ambient.a = 1.0f;
    // set ambient color to white
    m_Mat.Specular.r = 1.0f;
    m_Mat.Specular.g =1.0f;
    m_Mat.Specular.b =1.0f;
    m_Mat.Specular.a =1.0f;
    m_Mat.Power = 100.0f;

    m_pD3DDevice->SetMaterial(&m_Mat);

    // Create a texture using the with "test.tga" from the sprite labs.
    //Apply tri-linear filtering to the texture, by modifying the sampler states by calling the device's SetSamplerState().
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(m_pD3DDevice, L"test.png",&m_Texture);

    //Apply tri-linear filtering to the texture, by modifying the sampler states by calling the device's SetSamplerState().

    m_pD3DDevice->SetSamplerState( 0,D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
    m_pD3DDevice->SetSamplerState( 0,D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
    m_pD3DDevice->SetSamplerState( 0,D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
}

void DirectXGame::Update(HWND hWnd, bool& bWindowed, double dt)
{
}

void DirectXGame::Render()
{
    // if our d3d device was not craeted return
    if(!m_pD3DDevice)
        return;

    m_pD3DDevice->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET|D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,
    D3DCOLOR_XRGB(100,149,237), 1, 0); // 100,149,237 00255

    // Begin the scene
    if( SUCCEEDED( m_pD3DDevice->BeginScene() ) )
    {
        m_pD3DDevice->SetVertexDeclaration( vertDec);

        //set cube postion
        D3DXMATRIX translation, rotation, scale, world, position;
        float index = 0.0f; index+=0.05f;
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translation,0,0,0);
        D3DXMatrixRotationY(&rotation, timeGetTime()/1000);
        D3DXMatrixScaling(&scale,1,1, 1.0f);

        world = scale*rotation*translation;

        m_pD3DDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &world);

        // select the vertex and index buffers to use
        m_pD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_TRUE);
        m_pD3DDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_SPECULARENABLE, TRUE );
        m_pD3DDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_AMBIENT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(60,60,60));
        m_pD3DDevice->SetStreamSource(0, VB, 0, sizeof(Vertex));
        m_pD3DDevice->SetIndices(IB);
        m_pD3DDevice->SetMaterial(&m_Mat);
        m_pD3DDevice->SetTexture( 0,m_Texture);

        m_pD3DDevice->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST,//D3DPRIMITIVETYPE Type
            0,/*BaseVertexIndex*/
            0, //* MinIndex*/
            24, /*NumVertices*/
            0, /*StartIndex*/
            12);//PrimitiveCount

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //Font 1 "Name"
        RECT rct;
        rct.bottom = m_nHeight;
        rct.top=2;
        rct.left=658;
        rct.right=m_nWidth;

        //for the font2 FPS
        RECT rect;
        rect.bottom = m_nHeight;
        rect.top =2;
        rect.left = 10;
        rect.right = m_nWidth;

        wchar_t buffer[64];
        swprintf_s(buffer, 64,L"Frames Per Second: %d", m_FPS);
        m_pD3DFont->DrawText(0, buffer, -1, &rect, DT_TOP | DT_NOCLIP, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255,255,255,255));

        // Create a colour for the text ( blue)
        D3DCOLOR fontColor = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255,0,0,255);

        //draw the text
        m_pD3DFont->DrawText(NULL, L"Mariana Serrato", -1, &rct, 0, fontColor ); // move test to far right

        // End the scene
        m_pD3DDevice->EndScene();

        // present the back buffer to the screen
        m_pD3DDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        //calculate Frames Per Second
        m_currTime = timeGetTime();
        static int fspCounter = 0;
        if(m_currTime - m_prevTime >= 1000.0f)
        {
            m_prevTime = m_currTime;
            m_FPS = fspCounter;
            fspCounter =0;
        } else {
            ++fspCounter;
        }
    }
}

void DirectXGame::Shutdown()
{
    SAFE_RELEASE(VB);
    SAFE_RELEASE(IB);
    SAFE_RELEASE(vertDec);
    SAFE_RELEASE(m_pD3DFont);
    SAFE_RELEASE(m_Texture);
    SAFE_RELEASE(m_Sprite);
    SAFE_RELEASE(m_pD3DDevice);
    SAFE_RELEASE(m_pD3DObject);
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
.h header file

## pragma once

## include  // for random nums

## include

## include

## include

## include

## include

## include "DirectXInput.h"

## include

## include

## pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")

## pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9.lib")

## pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")//for timeGetTime()

## pragma comment(lib, "dinput8.lib")

## pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")

// Macro to Safely release com obejcts

## define SAFE_RELEASE(x) if(x) {x->Release(); x = 0;}

// Direct Input version

## define DIRECTINPUT_VERSION 0x0800

// Define window size

## define SCREEN_WIDTH 800

## define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

//#define D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX (D3DFVF_XYZ|D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)

class DirectXGame
{
    struct Vertex
    {
        D3DXVECTOR3 position;
        D3DXVECTOR3  normal;
        D3DXVECTOR2 uv;
    };
    IDirect3D9*             m_pD3DObject;
    IDirect3DDevice9*       m_pD3DDevice;

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS   m_D3Dpp; 
ID3DXFont*              m_pD3DFont; //Font
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9      m_Texture;
ID3DXSprite*            m_Sprite;//Sprite
D3DXVECTOR3             texCenter,eyePos,lookAt,upVec;
D3DCAPS9                m_D3DCaps; //D3D Device Caps
D3DLIGHT9               m_Light;
D3DMATERIAL9            m_Mat; 
D3DVERTEXELEMENT9       m_Element;
D3DXMATRIX              view_Matrix, pro_Matrix;

// cube
Vertex m_cubeVerts[24];
WORD m_cubeIndices[36];
IDirect3DVertexBuffer9* VB;
IDirect3DIndexBuffer9* IB;  
IDirect3DVertexDeclaration9* vertDec;

bool m_bVSync;
char buffer [256];
int m_nWidth, m_nHeight;
int m_FPS,alfa[5],mFPS,mMilliSecPerFrame;
float m_currTime,m_prevTime,FOV, aspectRatio, nearPlane, farPlane;
DWORD D3DUSASE_DYNAMIC,D3DUSASE_WRITEONLY;
```

public:
    DirectXGame(void);
    ~DirectXGame(void);
    void Initialize(HWND hWnd,HINSTANCE hInst, bool bWindowed);
    bool isDeviceLost();
    void Update(HWND hWnd, bool& bWindowed, double dt);
    void Render();
    void CheckPosition();
    void Shutdown();

};

Comment: WAY too much code, and yet still not a complete repro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't enabled D3DRS_LIGHTING.

```
m_pD3DDevice->setRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, TRUE);
```

Comment: added it to the program and still am getting a black cube

Comment: This is marked as answer how i have this and my light still wont work